# Render Samples missing?

Tags: rendering

i have a issue with the render samples

when i set my GPU as render device i get 500 samples as i want. but when i change to CPU device, i dont see the number of samples

what do i miss?

CPU Device: no samples shown
[image]

Samples i set:

[image]

Device:

[image]

Comment: That number says *Path Tracing **Tile*** and is in fact the *tile size* (the rectangles which are rendered at once.

Comment: ya, u r rigth, just saw last numbers, not the name. but why does cpu device not show samples like gpu device?

Answer (score 1):

Blender has been made so that he displays the samples progression only when he renders one tile at the same time.
(Or if you check the "progressive refine" option as you force blender to render the entire picture sample after sample instead of waiting for each tile to get all its samples done before rendering the next tile).

This happens only when you set the tile size bigger than the final resolution, or use GPU  rendering (GPU has only one rendering unit) or constrain your CPU to use only one rendering unit (CPU nowadays have at least 2, most have 4, 6 or 8, high-end CPU can have 32, 64, ... And render farms can have hundreds of them).

If there are multiple tiles to render, Blender shows only the tiles progression. I guess it's mainly because they want to keep the rendering stats as simple as possible.

Considering that some computers can have several dozens of rendering units at the same time, I guess it's better to have just a tile progression instead of 64 different render samples progression.
I also guess it could be nice to give an optional "advanced stats" mode, letting the user choose what he wants to see, but that's another topic.

Answer (score 0):

this now can closed, got a answer in discord:
"the samples just will not shown, but have to be exactly the same."

i made a testrender with 50 and 5000 samples.
the time to render changed drasticly...
so we can make sure, its working, just not show